# Can not compare none type and int type

Tags: python

When I tried executing the function CalcPoints, I get the error message saying none and int can't be compared. I am unsure where I am getting the none type object from since I returned OldPoints in the first function.

```
def GetPoints(CardNum1):
    if CardNum1 == "1":
        OldPoints = 3000
        return OldPoints

def CalcPoints(CardNum, Total):
    if Total > 100:
        OldPoints = GetPoints(CardNum)
        if OldPoints > 2000:
            NewPoints = Total * 1.2
        else: 
            NewPoints = Total * 1.1
    else:
        NewPoints = 0
    return NewPoints
```

Comment: if `CardNum1` appears not to be `"1"` `GetPoints` implicintly returns `None`

Comment: There is no else in GetPoints, so if the first condition don't met , it will return None, put some else statement. if not clear just let know i will put as solution

Answer (score 0):

```
def GetPoints(CardNum1):
    OldPoints = 0
    if CardNum1 == "1":
        OldPoints = 3000
    return OldPointt
```

By default python function return None so, return int value for comparison

Answer (score 0):

First, You are missing some indent in functions.

GetPoints() will not return anything (None) if CarNum1 is different than "1".
Add else to this if statement with a default return value such as 0 or something else.